# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with AlertDialog in an asyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have a splash screen that runs an `asyncTask` that downloads data from an API. On that task's `OnPostExecute` I run the next `asyncTask` to send stored emails. Once that is complete I need an `AlertDialog` to popup with an ok button so the user knows the downloads are complete. I used this SO question to get as far as I have:

[Android AlertDialog inside AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489643/android-alertdialog-inside-asynctask)

Now I'm getting a NullPointerException when I attempt to add properties to the dialog:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     Context c;

     public JSONParser(int api,Context c) {
          this.api= api;
          this.c = c;
     }
     ...
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
          JSONObject output = new JSONEmailParser(c).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, new String[] {null,null,null,null}).get();
     }
}

public class JSONEmailParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     Context c;

     AlertDialog.Builder builder;

     public JSONEmailParser(Context c){
          this.c = c;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute(int api){
          builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
     }

     ...

     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
          setLastUpdate();

          builder.setTitle("Sales Toolkit");
          builder.setCancelable(false);
          builder.setMessage("Download Complete");
          builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    endSplash();
               }
          });
          builder.show();

        }
}
```

The error is coming up on `builder.setTitle("Sales Toolkit");`

Comment: You should always use the @Override annotation.  It helps catch errors like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like the `onPreExecute()` method is not being called. If you don't really need to use the `builder` anywhere before the `onPostExecute()` method, I would suggest just moving

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
```

into the `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 5):

`AsyncTask#onPreExecute()` doesn't take an int argument.  Since your method has the wrong signature, it is likely never being called, and therefore `builder` is never set.  This is a classic example of why you should use `@Override` annotations.

Comment: I'm using that int inside the `onPreExecute()` just removed it in the example above because it didn't pertain to the issue.

Comment: It was a good catch @Brodo! And @dcp if it was not called then it IS an issue.

Comment: It doesn't just pertain to the issue, it *is* the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a .get() to execute an AsyncTask as it will not be async anymore. And onPreExecute will not be called?